# System locking up upon shutting down

Tags: shutdown, freeze, error-handling, lock

Today upon shutting down my System I was greeted with loads of errors and informations i do not understand. This happened yesterday also and it didn't seem to continue to shut down "normally". The lines of text kept updating and i just caught one of them. Rebooting the PC and everything looks normal.

Should I be concerned? What Should I do?

[image]

[image: edit: it happened again and I was able to catch it]

Comment: What CPU are you using? What version of the BIOS do you have? Have you done any CPU overclocking in the BIOS?

Comment: I am using an i7 9700F. I dont know about my BIOS version but i didnt update it from the factory. Also the F series has overclocking disabled

Comment: I just added another image that might provide more information